# JavaScript - Only first of two functions execute

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml, prompt

I'm new to JavaScript. I have four numbers input via prompts. Of these four numbers I want the maximum value printed out and the minimum value printed out. I have a function to calculate the maximum value and a function to calculate the minimum value. The only thing that I can get to print out is the maximum number. The function for the minimum number doesn't appear to run after the function for the maximum number is finished. Any clarification on why this isn't working would be appreciated.

This is what I currently have:

```js
window.onload = max4;

var first_number = prompt("Please enter your first number", "");
var second_number = prompt("Please enter your second number", "");
var third_number = prompt("Please enter your third number", "");
var fourth_number = prompt("Please enter your fourth number", "");

function max4() {
  document.getElementById("max_result");
  max_result.innerHTML = "The larger of the four numbers you entered is: " + Math.max(first_number, second_number, third_number, fourth_number);
}

function min4() {
  document.getElementById("min_result");
  min_result.innerHTML = "The lowest of the four numbers you entered is: " + Math.min(first_number, second_number, third_number, fourth_number);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>JavaScript Test Project</title>
  <script src="min_max_numbers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Largest and Smallest</h3>
  <h5 id="max_result"></h5>
  <h5 id="min_result"></h5>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Reusing IDs (`max_result`) is not valid.

Comment: It wont execute the `min4` since in window load you have only called the funtion `max4` but you have not referred anywhere about `min4` to execute

Comment: max4 is called.  min4 is not.

Answer (score 0):

You are never invoking the function `min4`, you can invoke it after prompts:

```
var first_number = prompt("Please enter your first number", "");
var second_number = prompt("Please enter your second number", "");
var third_number = prompt("Please enter your third number", "");
var fourth_number = prompt("Please enter your fourth number", "");

max4(); //invoke max4 function
min4(); //invoke min4 function

function max4() {
  var max_result = document.getElementById("max_result");
  max_result.innerHTML = "The larger of the four numbers you entered is: " + Math.max(first_number, second_number, third_number, fourth_number);
}

function min4() {
  var min_result = document.getElementById("min_result");
  min_result.innerHTML = "The lowest of the four numbers you entered is: " + Math.min(first_number, second_number, third_number, fourth_number);
}
```

Comment: as a side note - you also are never defining `max_result` or `min_result`

Comment: the DOM isn't loaded yet so it won't get the ID anyways. I doubt this approach will work @hackerrdave

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to call both the functions in `window.onload`

This is done as follows. Refactor your JS file as follows

```
window.onload = func1;

var first_number = prompt("Please enter your first number", "");
var second_number = prompt("Please enter your second number", "");
var third_number = prompt("Please enter your third number", "");
var fourth_number = prompt("Please enter your fourth number", "");

function max4(){
    document.getElementById("max_result").innerHTML = "The larger of the four numbers you entered is: " + Math.max(first_number, second_number, third_number, fourth_number);
}

function min4(){
    document.getElementById("min_result").innerHTML = "The lowest of the four numbers you entered is: " + Math.min(first_number, second_number, third_number, fourth_number);
}

function func1() {
    max4();
    min4();
}
```